# How can I make my puzzles twice as long?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

I feel like many of the puzzles I post here are too short...

*How can I make them twice as long?*

[image]

Transcription:

```
Beer mug (5)
Bosc, e.g. (4)
Cappuccino alternative (5)
Coastline (5)
Parasite's home (4)
Rescue, with "out" (4)
Segment of an act (5)
Wheat or rye (5)

⮕

Type of consonant [4]
Snitch [1]
Guts [3]
.
Aging [6]
Farrier [7]

Experts [4]
.
.
.
.
.
.
Show up again [2]
Indicting [3]
.
```

Comment: Whoa, good puzzle!

Comment: rot13(Fpvagvyyrfprag!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The clues on the left solve straightforwardly:

> **STEIN** Beer mug (5)
> **PEAR**  Bosc, e.g. (4)
> **LATTE** Cappuccino alternative (5)
> **SHORE** Coastline (5)
> **HOST**  Parasite's home (4)
> **BAIL**  Rescue, with "out" (4)
> **SCENE** Segment of an act (5)
> **GRAIN** Wheat or rye (5)

The clues on the right are

> doubled up anagrams of the words from the left:
> **BILABIAL**      Type of consonant [4]
> **TATTLETALE**    Snitch [1]
> **INTESTINES**    Guts [3]
>                   .
> **SENESCENCE**    Aging [6]
> **HORSESHOER**    Farrier [7]
>
> **HOTSHOTS**      Experts [4]
>                   .
>                   .
>                   .
>                   .
>                   .
>                   .
> **REAPPEAR**      Show up again [2]
> **ARRAIGNING**    Indicting [3]
>                   .

Taking the

> letter indexed by the number in square brackets yields: **ATT.CH S......ER.**

If we take the

> letters, double them and anagram them we get **ATTACH STRETCHERS**, which is how you can make a puzzle twice as long!